# Triangle optimization problem

Tags: inequality, analytic-geometry, triangles

Let $a,b,c$ be the sides of a triangle , then what is the maximum and minimum values (if exist) of the following quantities

(i) $\dfrac {a^2b^2c^2}{(a+2b)(a+2c)(b+2c)(b+2a)(c+2a)(c+2b)}$

(ii) $\dfrac {abc(a+b+c)^3}{(a+2b)(a+2c)(b+2c)(b+2a)(c+2a)(c+2b)}$

Comment: Probably you should try to find a more informative title which includes not just formulas.

Answer (score 1):

(i) 
\begin{align*}
&\dfrac {a^2b^2c^2}{(a+2b)(a+2c)(b+2c)(b+2a)(c+2a)(c+2b)}\\
=&\dfrac{1}{(1+2\frac{b}{a})(1+2\frac{a}{b})(1+2\frac{c}{a})(1+2\frac{a}{c})(1+2\frac{c}{b})(1+2\frac{b}{c})}
\end{align*}
For each two factors, for example, $(1+2\frac{b}{a})(1+2\frac{a}{b})=5+2(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a})\geqslant5+2\cdot2$

(ii) 
\begin{align*}
&\dfrac {abc(a+b+c)^3}{(a+2b)(a+2c)(b+2c)(b+2a)(c+2a)(c+2b)}\\
=&\frac{(a+b+c)^3}{(1+2\frac{b}{a})(1+2\frac{c}{b})(1+2\frac{a}{c})(a+2c)(b+2a)(c+2b)}
\end{align*}
Note that $(1+2\frac{b}{a})(1+2\frac{c}{b})(1+2\frac{a}{c})=9+2(\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{b}+\frac{a}{c})+4(\frac{c}{a}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{a}{b})\geqslant9+2\cdot3+4\cdot3$ and $(a+2c)(b+2a)(c+2b)$

Comment: (ii) is homogeneous.

Comment: How does it go? Your proof is not finished.

Comment: @MaMing, I suspended it, I found my idea not working.